# select would indicate pipe is readable when there's no data in pipe and write end is closed?

Tags: file-descriptors, select

I am reading *The Linux Programming Interface*.

From *63.2.3 When Is a File Descriptor Ready?*, it says:

> Correctly using `select()` and `poll()` requires an understanding of
>   the conditions under which a file descriptor indicates as being ready.
>   SUSv3 says that a file descriptor (with `O_NONBLOCK` clear) is
>   considered to be ready if a call to an I/O function would not block,
>   *regardless of whether the function would actually transfer data*. The key point is italicized: `select()` and `poll()` tell us whether an
>   I/O operation would not block, rather than whether it would
>   successfully transfer data. In this light, let us consider how these
>   system calls operate for different types of file descriptors. We show
>   this information in tables containing two columns:
>
> - The `select()` column indicates whether a file descriptor is marked as readable (r), writable (w), or having an exceptional condition (x).
>
> ....
>
> Pipes and FIFOs
>
> Table 63-4 summarizes the details for the read end of a pipe or FIFO.
>   The `Data in pipe?` column indicates whether the pipe has at least 1
>   byte of data available for reading. In this table, we assume that
>   `POLLIN` was specified in the `events` field for `poll()`.
>
> ....
>
> Table 63-4: `select()` and `poll()` indications for the read end of a
>   pipe or FIFO
>
> ```
> Condition or event              | select()   | poll()
> Data in pipe? | Write end open? |            
> no            | no              | r          | POLLHUP
> yes           | yes             | r          | POLLIN
> yes           | no              | r          | POLLIN | POLLHUP
> ```
>
> And Table 63-5: `select()` and `poll()` indications for the write end
>   of a pipe or FIFO
>   (In this table, we
>   assume that `POLLOUT` was specified in the events field for `poll()`.)
>
> ```
> Condition or event                          | select()   | poll()
> Space for PIPE_BUF bytes? | Read end open?  |            
> no                        | no              | w          | POLLERR
> yes                       | yes             | w          | POLLOUT
> yes                       | no              | w          | POLLOUT | POLLERR
> ```

I don't understand the 1st row condition of both tables.

No data in pipe, write end closed, `select()` would indicate that as a readable file descriptor? Why? Shouldn't `select()` block till there's data in the pipe?

No space for `PIPE_BUF` bytes, read end closed, `select()` would indicate that as a writeable file descriptor?

Comment: You even reproduced the italicization of the key point.  (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had the pipe (the read end) open, there was no data *but* the write end was also open. If you do a `read()` in this situation, you'll block - and `select()` would not report the FD as readable. I think we're in agreement on this, right?

Now suppose you're in the middle of this blocking `read()` and the writer `close()`s their end of the pipe. What happens? Your `read()` returns, with a result of `0`. And pretty much the same thing would happen if you call `read()` *after* the writer `close`s. Only you would not block - `read` would return immediately, also with a `0` result. Ergo, by the reasoning in the source you quoted, your FD is "readable" - or perhaps it would be better said "not blockable", and that is what `select` actually reports.

If you try coding up a little example, you'll see that this definition in fact leads to cleaner, more elegant code than the more "intuitive" definition you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much. Now I get it. Somehow I was **mistakenly** thinking that `select()` should block if no data in pipe and write end is closed. It should mark as readable and return `0` as you said. My bad :(

Answer (score 0):

System call select(2) (and poll (2)) will block on the read end of a FIFO if the write end has never been opened before (that is on Linux).

In contrast both will NOT block on the read end of a PIPE if the write end HAS BEEN CLOSED.

The difference is that FIFOs are created w/ both ends CLOSED, while pipes are created w/ both ends OPENED.
select(2) (and poll(2)) reproduces what happened in the early days of Unix, when only blocking synchronization existed (before the intro of select(2) and the BSD socket API - in general before non-blocking was introduced in Unix).

As opening of the read end of a FIFO was only successful after the write end had been opened as well, read(2) always looked into a FIFO w/ a OPENED write end. Therefore it is only logical that both select(2) and poll(2) block on the read end of a FIFO (only possible if the read end has been opened w/ O_NONBLOCK) if the write end has never been opened before.

And yes, the LPI is only correct in table 63-4 with regard to FIFOs if the write end has been opened (and closed by the last writer) at least once.